# How to combine two DStreams(pyspark)?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, pyspark, kafka-python

I have a kafka stream coming in with some input topic. 
This is the code i wrote for accepting kafka stream.

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appname) 
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
ssc = StreamingContext(sc) 
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topics,\ 
            {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
```

Then I create two DStreams of the keys and values of the original stream.

```
keys = kvs.map(lambda x: x[0].split(" ")) 
values = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1].split(" "))
```

Then I perform some computation in the values DStream. 
For Example,

```
val = values.flatMap(lambda x: x*2)
```

Now, I need to combine the keys and the val DStream and return the result in the form of Kafka stream.

How to combine val to the corressponding key?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `join` operator on the 2 DStreams to merge them.
When you do map, you are essentially creating another stream. So, join will help you merge them together.

Eg:

```
Joined_Stream = keys.join(values).(any operation like map, flatmap...)
```

Comment: I did not get this part `(any operation like map, flatmap...)`, Can you elaborate more.

Comment: I don't understand the thing which you want to actually do (I provided a generic answer of merging 2 DStreams).
The thing is if you do a flatmap on the values, there is no way to map them back to keys as the output of that would be one flattened list....
By merging 2 Dstreams you can create RDDs each with elements of both keys & values, just that there would not be a one to one mapping...